# Unittest Angular4 Effect and HttpClient

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I have a working Angular 4.4.6 application (NgRx 2.x) which I am migrating to the new HttpClient. Everything is working fine after migration, except for a unittest.

I have 1 @Effect which performs a HttpClient.get and returns a simple JSON response. 
In the unittest I get a 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined' in the Effect, which when running the application works fine.

**Any pointers what I am doing wrong?**
What I did not expect is that on the console.log line in the @Effect catch ( get the 'Cannot read property 'data' of undefined' TypeError.

**Effect**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Actions, Effect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LOAD_SESSION_DATA, LoadSessionDataFailedAction, LoadSessionDataSuccessAction } from './session-data.actions';
import { SessionData } from './session-data.model';

@Injectable()
export class SessionDataEffects {

  @Effect() loadSessionData$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_SESSION_DATA)
    .switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get('/session-data')
      .map((data: SessionData) => new LoadSessionDataSuccessAction({data}))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        return Observable.of(new LoadSessionDataFailedAction());
      }));

  constructor(private actions$: Actions,
              private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }
}
```

**Unittest:**

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { EffectsRunner, EffectsTestingModule } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppModule } from '../../app.module';
import { LoadSessionDataAction, LoadSessionDataSuccessAction } from './session-data.actions';
import { SessionDataEffects } from './session-data.effects';
import { SessionData } from './session-data.model';
import { sessionDataReducer } from './session-data.reducer';

describe('SessionData effects', () => {
  let runner: EffectsRunner;
  let effects: SessionDataEffects;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        AppModule,
        EffectsTestingModule,
        StoreModule.provideStore(sessionDataReducer)
      ]
    });

    runner = TestBed.get(EffectsRunner);
    effects = TestBed.get(SessionDataEffects);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should return a LoadSessionDataSuccessAction', () => {
    const stubResponseBody: SessionData = {datasource: 'test-datasource'};
    runner.queue(new LoadSessionDataAction());

    effects.loadSessionData$.subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(new LoadSessionDataSuccessAction({data: stubResponseBody}));
      });

    const req = httpMock.expectOne('/session-data');
    req.flush(stubResponseBody);
  });
});
```